# How to show the node in Sankey diagram when there is no link after the node

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-google-charts

I want to show the node even it does not have linkage after. But currently when I added in the labels float at the top of the chart.

Refer the example here, https://codesandbox.io/s/elastic-euclid-qhhkvd?file=/src/App.tsx 
I want to show Failed and Deleted nodes same column as Passed even no linkage for them. 
[The floated labels were highlighted with red box](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lo12U.png)